# Trouble comparing smallint in where clause

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have a table with a column called status of type smallint and accepts null.  Sql server 2000.

My data contains mostly 2 in that field, but also 0 and null.

When I do

```
select *
from table
 where status <> 2
```

I don't get all the proper records (where status is null or 0).  Any idea why this is happening and how to correct?  Shouldn't <> give me everything other than 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from table
 where ISNULL(status, 1) <> 2
```

[NULL doesn't compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191270.aspx): so remove it.

Your example is the "common mistake" on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29#Common_mistakes) too...

Comment: So I feel stupid until I see the "Criticisms" section where people complain about how it works.  Still, don't know how I missed that entry...

Comment: This NULL thing just *is*. I've better things to complain about :-)

Answer (score 2):

The NULL test doesn't match any arithmetic comparison.

use

```
where status <> 2 OR status is null
```

Comment: Really?  So the statement: 2 <> null is false?  Why does this happen?

Comment: Because NULL is not a value put in the field.  It is a status condition about the field, stored elsewhere.

Comment: Ok, it works.  But its very confusing from a mathematic standpoint.  2 and null (nothing) are NOT the same thing.

Comment: @MAW74656 - Not even `SELECT 1 WHERE NULL=NULL` returns any rows.

Comment: So null doesn't equal null?  Weird!

Comment: @MAW74656:  Yep, but `WHERE status IS NULL = status IS NULL` works.

Comment: @wallyk - Not in SQL Server. It doesn't have a boolean datatype.

Comment: @Martin- Yeah, but it should, messing around with bit is a pain.  I usually use a smallint anyway, but then I have to lookup the meaning of each code.

Answer (score 1):

What you're expecting can be accomplished by setting ANSI_NULLS to off.

For example, try running these queries:

```
set ansi_nulls off
select case when 1 != null then 'true' else 'false' end

set ansi_nulls on
select case when 1 != null then 'true' else 'false' end
```

That being said, this is very non-standard SQL behaviour that you're expecting to see. NULL comparisons should always be considered false whether equals to or not equals to comparisons, as every developer will expect that type of SQL query behaviour.

Your WHERE clause should then look like:

```
where status <> 2 or status is null
```

Another option would be just to compare to status = 1, if that is the only status that you're expecting to be included in your query.